# Why are HTTP requests delayed in ASP.NET Web API?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I'm just diving into Web API development (ASP.NET 4.6, Visual Studio 2015) and I have a strange problem. When running my web application with the startup option "Don't open a page. Wait for a request from an external application" selected, the initial request that is supposed to kick things off is very delayed.

For example, I start debugging and the VS output window is blank. I figure this is normal. Then in Fiddler I send the initial request. The time it takes for VS to start spitting out debug information and actually spinning up the application varies: sometimes it is instantly, most of the time it is about 10 seconds. Occasionally it will take up to 1 minute. During that time *nothing is happening*.

**Edit:**

Clarification: this is a delay before ANYTHING happens (i.e. before bootstrapping/spin-up occurs)

This mysterious delay also occurs when the project is configured to start with the default MVC home page. And it also happens when running without debugging. This happens with fresh project made from the template. Same goes for ASP.NET 5 template app. Also happens when I run in full IIS.

I wonder if it's a problem specific to my computer, as I tried all these things on another machine and there were never any delays.

Comment: You mean the delay when, on first request, asp.net compiles your website?

Comment: No, a delay before ANYTHING happens. In other words, typically 10 seconds after I send the request, then all the bootstrapping/spin-up occurs

Comment: That's an important clarification, should probably go in an [edit].

Answer (score 1):

I found out what was stalling out the HTTP request: my antivirus. I have AVG Internet Security Business Edition on my system. All that was required was to select "Temporarily Disable AVG Protection". Boom--right away, all my HTTP requests came through instantly.

Additional info: I tried disabling individual components from the AVG control panel, but none of those provided the fix. It seems, unfortunately, that it's all-or-nothing with AVG.

**Conclusion:**
At least on my system, completely disabling AVG (or presumably, uninstalling) AVG is required for ASP.NET development where waiting up to 1 minute for the first request to be processed is unacceptable.